# UILocalNotification on the due date, weekly and monthly report

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, notifications

I am trying to work out the best way to use local notification in background to run a method to display a notification message from core data, based on due date or upcoming weekly and monthly summary report.

There are two options which I have worked out which is NSTimer and UILocalNotification.

With NSTimer i can run scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval every 24 hours in background to check core data before display local Notification to see if it is on due date, weekly or monthly report. I am not sure if this is best solutions or recommendation?

I have read other posts, they suggestion to use UILocalNotification instead. But they are only limited to 64 notifications per app. Thats ok if I use weekly and monthly which total 64 notifications but it won't work after 1 year unless user active the app also I need to display due date's on the day message as well.

I am thinking maybe after a local notification displayed then the app still in background set new next schedule local notification, but I couldn't work this one out so not sure if this is possible?

Any suggestions on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of app do you need there to be a notification every week but the user never go into the app? 64 should be plenty, NSTimer in the background at all, every time you background the app it gets invalidated, unless you were to use some background hack to make sure it still runs, but even then I don't think timers fire.

Comment: thanks for your response, the app is for bills due notification. user want know what total of their bills each week and each month and notify when the bill is due on the day. I have tested on iPhone Simulator the NSTimer with repeat didn't get invalidated when test 1 minute for an hour.

Comment: Make sure you test on the device as well. Sometimes you can get different results! I've run into that before where something worked perfectly on the simulator related to backgrounding (playing specific alert) but failed miserably on device.

Comment: Cool thanks for the info. I m thinking to tell the user on 64th notification to active the app to continue receive notifications if they have not run the app until 64th notification. Cheers